# JMeter Issue in VLAN enabled system

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, vlan

Once my machine is VLAN enabled, I'm neither able to prepare new scripts using JMeter-2.9 tool nor able to execute my old scripts which I used to run earlier on the same machine.

Please find below error message I got while running the old scripts:

```
*Thread Name: 46_Drug Issue 1-1
Sample Start: 2014-11-19 16:22:40 IST
Load time: 1001
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 1720
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 1720
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.ConnectException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Connection refused: connect
Response headers:
HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null*
```

While recording a new test plan in my Windows machine, I'm able to navigate the different pages with HTTP Proxy server enabled in JMeter tool, but no HTTP request is getting recorded in the transaction controller.

Can anyone please suggest, how to overcome this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

According to me issue is related to proxy.

Jmeter sits between your machine and proxy and thats how it records all the requests coming to and going from your machine. It doesnt matter you are in VLAN or WAN if your proxy settings are correct.

Please check your proxy settings once put apply similar proxy settings `(Localhost,8080)` in VLAN or else you can provide seperate proxy for your Jmeter by starting it with JMeter parameters,

```
Jmeter.bat -H <hostname> -P <port> -u <username> -a <pwd>
```

Comment: As per my knowledge, the proxy settings will come into picture only when recording the new script in JMeter, but it does not matter while executing any existing script. I can manually access the application with the default LAN settings in IE. The existing script execution containing the correct URL of the application is not working in my machine, but the same script is working in different machines which are not VLAN-enabled. That's why I doubt VLAN is the culprit here. Proxy settings and the exact way you have mentioned to start the JMeter are also verified, still issue persists.