# Unable to login into application when using jmeter's recording controller

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I'm able to login into the application, when I'm NOT recording the jmeter script using jmeter's proxy server (aka Test Script Recorder).  But, as soon as I setup my browser to use jmeter's proxy server (aka Test Script Recorder) for recording, I'm NOT able to login into the application itself.  I have tried adding a cookie manager, cache manager, etc.., but nothing seems to make a difference.

When **NOT using** the proxy (i.e., when not recording script), below are the 2 calls that are made by the browser to successfully authenticate (screenshot from Chrome developer tools):

[image]
[image]

When **using** jmeter's proxy (i.e., when recording script), below is the call.  Looks like the call is not even made from the browser to the server, as even the remote address is not resolved and the request method is not shown.

[image]

I have recorded multiple scripts for authentication, but this is the first time I'm encountering this issue.  And I've followed [`this guide`](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) step by step. What am I missing?

Comment: run jmeter via proxy

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27017107/jmeter-issue-in-vlan-enabled-system

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [Jmeter manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html),

If you are testing from behind a firewall/proxy server, you may need to provide JMeter with the firewall/proxy server hostname and port number. To do so, run the jmeter[.bat] file from a command line with the following parameters:

-H [proxy server hostname or ip address] 
-P [proxy server port] 
-N [nonproxy hosts] (e.g. *.apache.org|localhost) 
-u [username for proxy authentication - if required] 
-a [password for proxy authentication - if required] 
Example : jmeter -H my.proxy.server -P 8000 -u username -a password -N localhost

You can also use --proxyHost, --proxyPort, --username, and --password as parameter names

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  But there isn't a firewall/proxy server involved in my case.  The site I'm trying to test is on the Internet.

Comment: can you attach the script or screenshot with open the httprequestdefault?

Comment: As per your information, there is browser specific proxy for accessing the application. am i right?.

Comment: no there isn't a browser specific proxy for the application itself.  I only set the browser's proxy settings to route all traffic via jmeter's proxy server (aka HTTP Test Script Recorder), so I can record my actions (i.e., the script).

Comment: and the issue is: when not recording the script, i can login without any issues.. but when recording the script, i'm not able to login. the browser is not even sending the request to the server, as you can see in my screenshot.

Comment: can you show the HTTP Request Defaults configuration control? might be configuration issue.