# Recording with jmeter when you cannot edit network settings

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

My machine is connected on LAN and I can't edit LAN setting.

How can I record a script using `jmeter`?

when I edit the browser network setting and start recording, faced an error.
I also tried to open `jmeter` with command line which also didn't work.

In `jmeter`, I am not able to run the previous recorded files also. I faced certification failure.. error.

I have deployed certificate inside bin directory.

Comment: Did you import "Root CA certificate" in your browser?

Comment: You don't have to change LAN setting. Use lan proxy as Jmeter proxy while starting and running the JMeter. This will be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27017107/jmeter-issue-in-vlan-enabled-system/27017263#27017263

Answer (score 0):

The majority of browsers are pre-configured for not using proxy for localhost/127.0.0.1 requests.

Make sure that your browser's proxy configuration looks like

[image: Firefox Proxy]

If this tweak doesn't resolve your issue you can try following recommendations from [Recording HTTPS Traffic with JMeter's Proxy Server](http://blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server) guide.